# rails 4 - postgres query syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a rails 4 demo app, and I'm stumped by an activerecord query.

There's two main tables: `widgets` and `orders`. The customer can enter an `order` for `widgets`, which have a variable price. Until a site admin closes a deal and sets the `final_price` for the `widget`, the `widgets.final_price` is `NULL` and the order is still open.

I want to select closed orders so I write something like this:

```
@closed = Order.joins(:widget).where("orders.buyer_id = :user_id AND widgets.final_price IS NOT NULL", {user_id: current_user})
```

In my rails log this queries the DB like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" INNER JOIN "widgets" ON "widgets"."id" = "orders"."widget_id" WHERE (orders.buyer_id = 2 AND widgets.final_price IS NOT NULL)
```

However, at the moment none of the `widgets` have a final price-- I verify this in the postresql admin, querying:

```
SELECT * FROM "widgets" WHERE widgets.final_price IS NOT NULL // returns 0 results
```

Yet in the activerecord query above, `@closed.count` returns 5, and `@closed.inspect` shows 5 records. How can this be, when I verified that there's no values for `widget.final_price`?

Comment: Make sure you're not mixing up your production database with your development database (if you have both).

Comment: If your ActiveRecord code was `@closed = Order.joins(:widget).where("orders.buyer_id = :user_id AND widgets.final_price IS NOT NULL", {user_id: current_user})` it would not show up in your logs as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders"...` since there's no `count` aggregate function specified in your code.

Comment: Have you backtracked from `orders` to `widgets` to see what the `final_price`s are? You're only getting five records so this should be pretty easy.

Comment: @franksort-- you're right, that's actually from the `@closed.count` statement in the view-- same query though, minus the count, correct?

Comment: @muistooshort-- I did check the actual `widgets` table and searched for records where `widgets.final_price IS NOT NULL` and it returned no results.